# Dialogflow Fulfillment Error during cloud function deployment

Tags: google-cloud-platform

My issue: I tried to Add Service Account and Calendar ID to Fulfillment via the inline editor on Dialogflow 's index.js code page. I enter I hit the Deploy button and Dialogflow outputs - Error happened during cloud function deployment. The code I pasted is below. I would appreciate any instruction on how to remove this error so I can move to the step in Fulfillment: How to Integrate Dialogflow with Google Calendar. You can reference the YouTube Video here  https://youtu.be/4_MvIf_ULgc
I entered the required information and the examples of my code without IDs and private keys.

```
// Ex:
const calendarId = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx0@group.calendar.google.com';
//Ex:
const serviceAccount = {
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "sample",
...
};
```

Thanks In Advance!

Comment: Never post private keys in public forums. Also, you should not publish your project IDs or account names (as seen in the block of code and screenshot of this question). I highly encourage you to revoke those credentials ASAP.

Comment: Oh.. Should I make any changes as far as my private keys?

Comment: They're compromised. Revoke them and generate new ones. Don't do _anything_ else until you've revoked them. Don't even get up from your chair.

Comment: I have revoked those credentials

Comment: Kindly help us in providing debugging logs.Check for detailed logs:
1. View cloud function log in GCP console
Next to the deploy button, there is a link "View execution logs in the Google Cloud".You can also access directly through the project console.
2. View detailed response using developer tool in browser
You  can inspect from the web browser using developer tool to see if you get any detailed response  deploying fails.